# Adding PHP form validation with succes message on top of Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I have a working Java script validation code that checks my contact form and submits it,  I want to add server side validation with PHP that will show sucess message once the form submitted correctly and that will send the details to my email.I am not sure how I suppose to include my php validation with my Java script one and how to show the success message. What I have so far is:

HTML:

```
<form id="mc-form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="name" hidden>שם פרטי</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="cv form-control" placeholder="שם פרטי">
        <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="phone" hidden>טלפון</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="cv form-control" placeholder="טלפון">
        <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="email" hidden>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="cv form-control" placeholder="דואר אלקטרוני">
        <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="subject" hidden>נושא</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="cv form-control" placeholder="נושא">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="message" hidden>הודעה</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="cv form-control message" placeholder="השאירו את הודעתכם פה" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-custom-outline " value="שלח" > -->
    <button onclick='return validateForm()' class="btn btn-custom-outline " id="submit-button">שלח</button>
    <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
    <span class="success">Thank's for submitting the form</span>

    <br>
    <!-- <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>-->
    <!--<span class="error"></span> -->
</form>
```

My JS:

```
function validateName() {

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    if (name.length == 0) {

        producePrompt('Name is required', 'name-error', 'red')
        return false;

    }

    if (!name.match(/^[a-zא-ת]+(\s[a-zא-ת]+)*$/i)) {

        producePrompt('Letters only please.', 'name-error', 'red');
        return false;

    }


    return true;

}

function validatePhone() {

    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

    if (phone.length == 0) {
        producePrompt('Phone number is required.', 'phone-error', 'red');
        return false;
    }

    if (!phone.match(/([0-9\s\-]{7,})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/)) {
        producePrompt('Include only digits| min :8 ', 'phone-error', 'red');
        return false;
    }


    return true;

}

function validateEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    if (email.length == 0) {

        producePrompt('Email is required', 'email-error', 'red');
        return false;

    }

    if (!email.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-[0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/)) {

        producePrompt('Email Invalid', 'email-error', 'red');
        return false;

    }


    return true;

}

/*function validateMessage() {
  var message = document.getElementById('contact-message').value;
  var required = 30;
  var left = required - message.length;

  if (left > 0) {
    producePrompt(left + ' more characters required','message-error','red');
    return false;
  }

  producePrompt('Valid', 'message-error', 'green');
  return true;

}*/

function validateForm() {
    var vn = validateName();
    var vp = validatePhone();
    var ve = validateEmail();

    if (!vn || !vp || !ve) {
        jsShow('submit-error');
        producePrompt('Please fix errors to submit.', 'submit-error', 'red');
        setTimeout(function() {
            jsHide('submit-error');
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    } else {

    }

}

function jsShow(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

function jsHide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}




function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {

    document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;


}
```

PHP:

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = " ";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = $success = " ";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא-ת ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }

if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject = "";
  } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'ilonasemyweb@gmail.com';
      $subjectm = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subjectm, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

I have a working Java script validation code that checks my contact form and submits it,  I want to add server side validation with PHP that will show sucess message once the form submitted correctly and that will send the details to my email.I am not sure how I suppose to include my php validation with my Java script one and how to show the success message. What I have so far is:

Comment: You create `$success` variable in PHP but don't use it in your code.

Comment: if you want to same style of success error message of both javascript and php then you have to do it through ajax then it's possible

Comment: @can you please include some code example so I can understand better ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this best IMO, by using jquery. For that you have to adapt your PHP script a little to output json and store the error/success messages differently. Add a bit of jquery code to your existing javascript and not to forget, include the jquery library into you HTML somewhere at the bottom. For the sake of completion, i added a simple empty check on subject and message and hide the success message until the form is really sent.

Note: You might want to remove your email from your question :)

**HTML script**

```
<style>
    .error {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<form id="mc-form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="name" hidden>שם פרטי</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="cv form-control" placeholder="שם פרטי">
        <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="phone" hidden>טלפון</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="cv form-control" placeholder="טלפון">
        <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="email" hidden>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="cv form-control" placeholder="דואר אלקטרוני">
        <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="subject" hidden>נושא</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="cv form-control" placeholder="נושא">
        <span class='error-message' id='subject-error'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
        <label for="message" hidden>הודעה</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="cv form-control message" placeholder="השאירו את הודעתכם פה" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <span class='error-message' id='message-error'></span>
    </div>
    <!-- <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-custom-outline " value="שלח" > -->
    <button class="btn btn-custom-outline " id="submit-button">שלח</button>
    <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
    <span class="success">Thank's for submitting the form</span>

</form>

<!-- load jQuery libraries -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript/jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        function jsShow(id) {
            $('#'+id).show();
        }

        function jsHide(id) {
            $('#'+id).hide();
        }

        function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {

            $('#'+promptLocation).text(message).css('color', color).show();

        }

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zא-ת]+(\s[a-zא-ת]+)*$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters only please");
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("digitsonly", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /([0-9\s\-]{7,})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/.test(value);
        }, "Include only digits| min :8 ");

        $('.success').hide();

        $("#mc-form").validate({
            error: function(label) {
                $(this).addClass( "error" );
            },
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    digitsonly: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Please specify your name",
                    lettersonly: "Letters only please"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Phone number is required",
                    digitsonly: "Include only digits| min :8 "
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Email is required",
                    email: "Email Invalid"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "Subject is required"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Message is required"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                sendForm();
            }
        });

        function sendForm() {

            $('[id*="-error"]').text(''); // default hide all error messages

            event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission and therefore page reload

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process_form.php',
                data: $("#mc-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {

                        Object.keys(data['error']).forEach(function(key) {
                            producePrompt(data['error'][key], key+'-error', 'red');
                        });

                    }
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('mail_error')) {
                        alert('Could not send mail');
                    }
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
                        $('.success').show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
</script>
```

**PHP script**

```
// init error and success message variable to check for emptiness
$error_msg = array();
$success_msg = array();
$data = '';

// prevent warnings or errors from displaying, else you won't get proper json result
ini_set('display_errors',0);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error_msg['name'] = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא-ת ]*$/",$name)) {
            $error_msg['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $error_msg['email'] = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_msg['email'] = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $error_msg['phone'] = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            $error_msg['phone'] = "Invalid phone number";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $error_msg['subject'] = "Subject is required";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $error_msg['message'] = "Message is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subject = "";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if (empty($error_msg)){ // note that $lastname_error does not exists
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
        $subjectm = 'Contact Form Submit';
        if (mail($to, $subjectm, $message)){
            $success_msg = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';
        } else {
            $mail_error_msg = 'Could not send email';
        }


    }

    // set output data accordingly
    if(!empty($success_msg)) {
        $data = array('success'=>$error_msg);
    } else if(!empty($error_msg)) {
        $data = array('error'=>$error_msg);
    } else if(!empty($mail_error_msg)) {
        $data = array('mail_error'=>$mail_error_msg);
    }

    // output json that you can parse with jquery
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading your comment, it depends on what you mean by

> I copied pretty much everything you wrote

I tested the previous code on my server and it worked well. However without your javascript validation since i removed the validation function `return validateForm()` so that might have confused things. To make it really work and not mixing up plain javascript with jquery, i adapted the HTML and Javascript code, so that only jQuery is used.

Here are some troubleshooting tips in general for using ajax:

1. The php script that processes must only output json, nothing else.
2. Errors, warnings or  notices should not be displayed (disabled) in your processing script.
3. Make sure the file name in the ajax parameter url is correct.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the explanation , but I still can't make it work , it doesn't submit and doesn't show errors  ... I hade jquey earlier in my index.htm , I copied pretty much everyrhing you wrote , do I need to make changes in my code beyond that?

Comment: @SemSam please see my adapted answer

Comment: I finally made it work , the validation works perfectly, shows errors etc... but when all the fields filled correctly it won't let me send , It gives me to click the button , but nothing happens , when I look in console I got next error: Failed to load resource: file:///C:/Users/ilona/Desktop/BootstrapLandinPage/send.php: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
My php script name is send.php .

Comment: Try setting the path of the file `send.php`, relative to the root directory of your website. Probably your HTML script is in the same directory. In that case, set the path to `./send.php`. From seeing your website path i am **assuming** that you are not running a webserver on your computer. If so, your PHP script will not work. Let me know.

Comment: I currently running my project on localhost.. are you saying that it won't work on localhost ?Is it at least suppose to refresh the page and show the success message ? I set the path to ./send.php , it's still won't do anything , except the  validation and errors display .

Comment: Unless you run a local webserver on your desktop, like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) or [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for example, you will not be able to serve php files.

Comment: No not XAMPP related but PHP related. You can always check the php log file for errors, and (always good idea with ajax stuff) to install a web developer browser extension for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) / [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/web-developer/) or to use Edge developer, all by right clicking on browser and clicking 'Inspect'

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I am opening a new topic on that php issue ,because I cannot figure it out where it's coming from .